# MKReverseGeocoder autorelease/release question in Apple's CurrentAddress sample

Tags: ios, autorelease, mkreversegeocoder

I am looking at this code lifted straight from the MapViewController.m file in the [CurrentAddress sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html) available on Apple's web site:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [reverseGeocoder release];
    [mapView release];
    [getAddressButton release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation
{
    self.reverseGeocoder =
        [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate] autorelease];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
}
```

I am wondering what the function is of the autorelease when allocating the object. (The reverseGeocoder is an ivar in the MapViewController class set up with the retain property.) I have code similar to this in my application, and it seems to work either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting your `reverseGeocoder` property increments the retain count (+1), but since you're creating the object with `alloc`+`init` (+1), you need to `autorelease` (-1) so that you do not end up with a 2 retain count.

It does work either way, the only difference is that when you do *not* `autorelease`, you leak.

> The reverseGeocoder is an ivar

It sure is, but note that when you're using the `self.reverseGeocoder` form, you're not accessing the ivar directly - instead, you're calling the relevant `setReverseGeocoder:` function, that is either written by yourself or @synthesized by the compiler.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

And:
[What equivalent code is synthesized for a declared property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350563/what-equivalent-code-is-synthesized-for-a-declared-property)