# Is this how properties are declared behind the scenes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

I was wondering about how the setter methods get created and am I right in saying this:

Retain/Strong attribute:

```
- (void)setProperty:(Class *)class
{
    variable = [class retain];
}
```

Assign/Weak attribute:

```
- (void)setProperty:(Class *)class
{
    variable = class;
}
```

Copy attribute:

```
- (void)setProperty:(Class *)class
{
    variable = [class copy];
}
```

Are assign and weak even the same either?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All are not correct. Google and you will find same sample code of manual creation of setters and getters

Comment: Yeah, that's the general idea, but the devil is in the details.  With a retained property you need to be sure to release the prior one.  And several other minor points in case of concurrency, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What equivalent code is synthesized for a declared property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350563/what-equivalent-code-is-synthesized-for-a-declared-property); see also [Accessor implementation of properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129203/accessor-implementation-of-properties?lq=1)