# How to add some code to synthesized getter/setter while keeping synthesized code

Tags: objective-c, ios, declared-property

I need to, for example, execute `NSLog(@"Executed.")` every time my synthesized getter or setter gets called. I see 2 ways to do that:

1. Find some snippets that work probably like synthesized ones. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350563/what-equivalent-code-is-synthesized-for-a-declared-property) may help in that.
2. Use KVO: add some observer which will do the work.

All of them doesn't looks satisfactory clean for me.
So, subj.

**UPDAE:** Thank for answers, but directly overriding isn't a solution:
we loose synthesized code. If we "copy paste" "right" synthesized code from somewhere (even from apple forum where apple engineer gives us code) we should check that it isn't changed after next compiler release.

Comment: directly overriding _is_ a solution, its just not one that you like. KVO requires less change but can get messy if you want this log for every setter. It probably comes down to personal preference but the synthesized code isnt complicated

Comment: the getter and setter in synthesizes are not magic. @Stunner 's answer is right, nothing more in getters and setters is done. If you write ARC compatible you should get rid of memory management methods

Comment: They aren't magic, yes. But they may change and I don't want to return  and rewrite if changes aren't ignorable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an additional property, with your custom getter and setter, that does your own thing, and then accesses the @synthesized ones, like so:

Foo.h:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    int bar;
}

@property int bar;
@property int bar2;


@end
```

Foo.m:

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo

@synthesize bar;

- (int) bar2
{
    NSLog(@"getter");
    return self.bar;
}

- (void) setBar2:(int)newBar
{
    NSLog(@"setter");
    self.bar = newBar;
}
@end
```

and then your code:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
foo.bar2 = 1;
foo.bar2 += 2;
[foo release];
```

So you would use "bar2" as your property, but you get all the niceties out of the @synthesized bar.  Anything in bar would be set/get in a thread safe manner, and any additional logic in bar2 would not (which may not matter to you)

Comment: Huh. Ugly, but I haven't thought of it.

Comment: I dont think its too ugly. I'd swap the names "bar" and "bar2" so that your code would be written to set and get bar, as expected.  If/when you no longer need to use the additional statements, like NSLog, then you can comment out the custom setters and getters, and move the @synthesized versions back into place.

Comment: But you should change class structure. That's just ugly. Too much for such a little problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to add an observer to the synthesized property since it would be the most clean solution.

If you are not satisfied with this way you may just want to override the getter/setter?

Answer (score 1):

So in your interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *testString;
```

And in your implementation:

```
@synthesize testString; //this is used to generate a setter/getter if we don't override one of them

-(NSString *)testString {
    NSLog(@"Executed.");
    return testString;
}

-(void)setTestString:(NSString *)newValue {
    NSLog(@"Executed.");
    if (testString != newValue){
        [newValue retain];
        [testString release];
        testString = newValue;
    }
}
```